# Undefined local variable or Method - Testing Puppet Modules using Beaker

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, puppet, beaker

I'm quite new to all of this. I am trying to test out a puppet module using Beaker. I keep getting this:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `describe' for 
 #Beaker::TestCase:0x007fd6f95e6460
 /Users/user1/beaker/Puppet/puppet-files/spec/classes/unit_spec.rb:3  
 /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/beaker-3.24.0/bin/beaker:9  
 /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15  
 /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15.
 This is the command that I'm running - "beaker --hosts myhost.yaml --pre-suite spec".
```

My unit_spec.rb contains this:

```
  require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks'

  describe 'application' do
  context 'applied to supported operating system' do
  on_supported_os.each do |os, facts|
  context "#{os}" do
   let(:facts) do
     facts
   end

   context "without any parameters" do
     let(:params) {{ }}

     it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }
     it { is_expected.to contain_class('files') }
     end
    end
   end
  end


    context 'applied to unsupported operating system' do
    describe 'ubuntu-14-x86_64' do
    let(:facts) {{
     :osfamily        => 'Debian',
     :operatingsystem => 'Ubuntu'
      }}

    it { is_expected.to raise_error(Puppet::Error, /Ubuntu not supported/) }
    end
   end
  end
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Btw, I am using 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks' due to the fact that when I just used 'spec_helper' it gave me an error that it could not "load such file" even though it was there.

Also, I have tried doing

```
RSpec.Describe
```

That did not fix the issue either. I get the following error -

```
 NameError: undefined local variable or method `on_supported_os' for #Class:0x007f92a61d5e58
```

I realise that this might be an RSpec Puppet issue, as this module was previously tested through puppet RSpec, however now I am trying to test using Beaker and not quite sure how to fully achieve that!

Comment: try adding `require 'rspec'`.

Comment: I tried that, it's still giving me the -                                                  
`NameError: undefined local variable or method "on_supported_os" for #Class:0x007f92a61d5e58`

Comment: Where is `on_supported_os` defined?? You have not shown us in your code above.

Comment: After a quick google, I found [this](https://github.com/mcanevet/rspec-puppet-facts#installation) -- is that what you're using? Follow the installation instructions; i.e. somewhere (probably, but not necessarily, in `spec_helper.rb`) you need to `require 'rspec-puppet-facts'` and `include RspecPuppetFacts`.

Comment: I don't know, that's the thing. The module I am testing on already contained all that in the unit_spec.rb. I'm not even sure it is properly defined. If I do need to define it, I don't know where to do that.

Comment: @TomLord yeah I have already tried that , it does not work. The errors stay the same,

Comment: Oh, so is this code from an existing project, which worked on the previous developer's machine but not yours? Maybe you just need to `bundle install`?

Comment: @TomLord Yeah, it's from an existing project which now needs to be tested using Beaker instead, to determine whether Beaker is a suitable way of doing future testing, and at the moment it appears not. `bundle install` the spec folder?

Comment: Just run `bundle install` from anywhere within the project.

Comment: @TomLord When I run `bundle install` it just added some more gems and dependencies `Bundle complete! 9 Gemfile dependencies, 35 gems now installed.
Use bundle info [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.`. Then when I run the original beaker command it is displaying the same error .

Comment: What do you mean, "run the original beaker command"? If you're not already, then try: `bundle exec rspec spec/path/to/unit_spec.rb`. Is the original author of this code not available to show you the ropes?

Comment: ....For example, do you have any continuous integration service like `TravicCI`, `CircleCI` `Jenkins`, etc. which you could use to see how the tests are normally run?

Comment: `beaker --hosts myhost.yaml --pre-suite spec` -- this command. No not really, as this code was done quite a while ago. I think Travis and Jenkins are used but not for this specific task that I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up unit- and VM-based testing.

- [rspec-puppet](http://rspec-puppet.com/) (and [rspec-puppet-facts](https://github.com/mcanevet/rspec-puppet-facts)' `on_supported_os`) are for catalog-based unit testing. They do not require a VM, and can give you quick feedback on syntax, and logic of your module.
- [beaker](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker), and the recommended [beaker-rspec](https://github.com/puppetlabs/beaker-rspec) add-on, provide full end-to-end testing capabilities, using actual VMs, and testing a complete stack deploy (as defined in you tests).

The main entry point for existing modules is usually rake. Take a look at the existing rake tasks in the module using `rake -T`. In a well-written module it should have tasks for both rspec-puppet (usually called `spec`), and beaker (often called `beaker`, or `acceptance`).

If it is your own module, you also might want to look into the new [Puppet Development Kit](https://puppet.com/blog/develop-modules-faster-new-puppet-development-kit) to get the most important tools in a single installer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I will definitely look into this.